# Linear combination and sign of determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given $d+2$ vectors $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{d+2} \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Clearly, they are linearly dependent. However, we have better result: Let
$$
y_i = \begin{bmatrix} x_i\\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}. 
$$
They are also linearly dependent. Thus, there exists coefficients $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{d+2}$ that are not simultaneously zero which satisfy $a_1y_1 + a_2y_2 + \dots + a_{d+2}y_{d+2} = 0$ (or in other words, $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\dots+a_{d+2}x_{d+2}=0$ and $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{d+2}=0$).

Question is to determine sign of $a_i$. Obviously, it can be anything since we can just multiply all of the coefficients by $-1$. Nevertheless, there is some relation between sign of $a_i$ and sign of determinant of
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
y_1 & \cdots & y_{i-1} & y_{i+1} & \cdots & y_{d+2} 
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(d+1) \times (d+1)}. 
$$
For every $1 \leq i \leq d+2$,
$$
\frac{\operatorname{sign}(a_i)}{\operatorname{sign} 
\Bigl( \det \bigl( 
\begin{bmatrix} 
y_1 & \cdots & y_{i-1} & y_{i+1} & \cdots & y_{d+2} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\bigr) \Bigr)}
$$
is same. Any idea on how to prove this result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=1,\dots, d+1$, the $a_i's$ are the solutions of
$$
(y_1, y_2,\dots, y_{d+1})
\left (
\begin{array}{c}
a_1\\
a_2\\
\vdots\\
a_{d+1}
\end{array}
\right)=-a_{d+2}y_{d+2}$$
Using [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) for solving linear systems, the solution is given by
$$\begin{split}
a_i&=\frac{\det(y_1, \dots, y_{i-1}, -a_{d+2}y_{d+2},y_{i+1},\dots,y_{d+1})}{\det(y_1, \dots, y_{d+1})}\\
&= (-1)^{d-i}a_{d+2}\frac{\det(y_1, \dots, y_{i-1},y_{i+1},\dots, y_{d+2})}{\det(y_1, \dots, y_{d+1})}
\end{split}
$$
which gives the result but with a factor of $(-1)^i$. I'm not sure where I messed up.